# how do I position a circle div at the end of another div that acts as a bar?

Tags: html, css, geometry

I am trying to make a circle div act as a decorative part of a bar and I'm having a hard time positioning the circle. The idea is that the bar and circle act as a section divider. I want to have a bar and then a circle at the end of it (hopefully, the circle has text). I am also trying to make it a responsive circle. I tried setting the width to a certain % and then height as auto but that didn't work too well. Here is my jsfiddle.(http://jsfiddle.net/dbartolome/vzkbjh5h/1/)

The HTML and CSS code so far:

```
<div class="divider"><div class="circle"></div></div>
```

and CSS

```
div{  
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.divider{
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #20ffd0;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

.circle{
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #BADA55;
 text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the to the `<hr>` answer but here's one option too:
http://jsfiddle.net/dianaavila/jr91mub8/1/

```
<div id="work">
 <div class="divider"></div>
 <div class="circle"></div>
 ....
</div>
```

.

```
.circle{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #BADA55;
  text-align: right;
  float:right;
  margin-top:-45px;
```

}

```
.divider{
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #20ffd0;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 float:left;
}
```

I took the .circle out of the .divider container.
Float them right and left respectively.
Added a negative margin to the circle.

Comment: Thanks Diana! I like this a lot too. Since I'm trying to alternate which side the circle shows up, this looks like it's going to work better!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version:  http://jsfiddle.net/vzkbjh5h/4/

```
.divider{
 display: block;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #20ffd0;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}


.circle{
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #BADA55;
 float: right;
 margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Will try this one and Niels's.

Answer (score 0):

Don't abuse all those classes. A horizontal divider is an `hr` element, and you can put the circle in just fine with an absolutely positioned `:after` pseudo-element.

All the CSS you need then for the `<hr>`:

```
hr {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #20ffd0;
  height: 20px;
  border:0;
  position: relative;
  margin:50px auto;
}
hr:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:-40px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #BADA55;
}
```

The `top:-40px` corrects for the combined heights of circle and bar to center vertically, and the `margin` on the `hr` itself gives it the 'breathing space' to other content.

You can of course also apply this to `hr.big` or something else if you don't want to style all horizontal rules like this.

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/gumpyryd/).

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I'm looking for. Is there a way to make the circle responsive? I played around with using percentages for width and height (as suggested by some web pages I found) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Percentual sizing will get very messy because of the different elements 'tied together'. This applies to every solution for your issue though, not just this approach.

Comment: It turns out that I can't have the circle alternate sides as I go down the page and use more hr as dividers. I guess I might have to go with the div. I learned about the tag's limitation though!

Comment: Of course you can, use `hr:nth-of-type(odd):after { right:auto; left:0; }`. [Universally supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

Answer (score 0):

You can position the `.circle` absolutely to the bar.
Here is an updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzkbjh5h/3/)

I've changed `.circle` to

```
.circle{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #BADA55;
 text-align: center;
 left: 100%;
 top: -80px;
 line-height: 100px;
}
```

Adjust `top` parameter to change circle's vertical position. `Line-height` is equal to the circle's height to make the text centered vertically. `Text-align: center;` is for horizontal.